# Matlab print -dmeta command clips the wrong figure to the clipboard. How to fix?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, printing, clipboard

I have a MATLAB GUI project developed using the GUIDE tool under R2012a under Windows 7. It uses code like

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  h = figure()
  t = linspace(1,10,200);
  plot(t,sin(t))
  figure(1)
  save2word('myfile.doc')
```

This should save the figure to the windows clipboard. What actually happens is that the clipboard contains an image of the calling program.

If I change the code as follows, the expected image appears on the clipboard.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  h = figure()
  t = linspace(1,10,200);
  plot(t,sin(t))
  figure(1)
  save2word('myfile.doc', '-f1')
```

Using save2word in this way solves my problem, but I am puzzled why something that used to work changed. Could it be a Java update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`save2word`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3149-save2word/content/save2word.m) function provides a second argument which you could use to specify the figure to "print":

```
save2word('file.doc','-f1')
```

which ends up calling:

```
print -dmeta -f1
```

to copy the figure to clipboard.

Of course you can build the string programmatically: `sprintf('-f%d',hFig)` where `hFig` is the figure handle.

Answer (score 0):

To use save2word you need to call save2word, which I don't see you doing in this instance.  `print -demta` as you have it here just simply copies the active figure to the clipboard.  If you want to save it to a file you have to use `print -dmeta 'filename'`.

I guess it's possible that I don't fully understand what you're asking/saying here.  Are you saying that save2word uses `print -dmeta` in order to place the given figure into a word document?  It's important to note that save2word doesn't support saving multiple figures at once to a word document and that you will need to call it each time for each figure you want to save.

Comment: it seems I failed to make myself clear. My question is about print -dmeta, not about save2word. It just happens that print -dmeta is used in save2word. I have modified my GUIDE developed GUI to call

Comment: And again (I pressed return to enter code example, now I will inline it instead). figure(1); print -dmeta which should copy figure 1 to the clipboard. (Figure 1 exists). Instead, the calling GUI gets copied to the clipboard, as I can see by pasting it into paint.

Comment: Ok, I presume that you are pushing a button on the GUI to have it save the figure.  If you're doing that (or some variant of that) try making the figure you want to save the current figure.  You can do this by adding the line: `set(0, 'CurrentFigure', h)`  This will make figure with handles `h` the current figure but won't bring it to the front of the stack (so it won't be shown above your GUI).

Comment: Just to add a little more to this.  By clicking something in the GUI window you're effectively setting it as the current window which is why you're getting the GUI window in the clipboard instead of the figure you desire.

Comment: I have recreated the problem in a new test project, created with GUIDE.

Comment: It has just one button, and the callback function is as follows:  % --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
figure(1)
t = linspace(1,10,200);
plot(t,sin(t))
print -dmeta
pause(1)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting. If I set a breakpoint at the pause and paste into paint, I get the gui with the button, not the figure with the sine wave. Meanwhile I will try your suggestion in the test project.

Comment: Here is a revised version of my test program with your suggested improvement, but sadly the problem persists. The callback is called from a GUIDE generated GUI with just one button. When I paste on reaching a breakpoint at the pause() call, I get an image of the GUI, not the sine wave. `
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    h = figure()
    t = linspace(1,10,200);
    plot(t,sin(t))
    set(0, 'CurrentFigure', h) 
    print -dmeta
    pause(1) % for a breakpoint.`

Comment: It would be much easier to read and follow if you could just edit your question with the additional information.  I also won't be able to run anything in Matlab for a while since I'm at work currently.